# Polymorphism issue in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a polymorphous array and I need to fix the bottom two lines of code.
I'm having trouble understanding Polymorphism, and I'm trying to figure out it's logic.

In this code I'm assuming Animal = superclass, Dog = subclass, Cat = subclass:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[20];
animals[0] = new Dog();
animals[1] = new Cat();

//these two below don't work
Dog lassie = animals[0];
Cat fluffy = animals[1];
```

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to know that `animals[0]` always holds a Dog.

Comment: What would this do? `if(Math.random() < 0.5) animals[0] = new Dog(); else animals[0] = new Cat(); Dog d = animals[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work because the type of the array is `Animal`, which means the objects in the array are of type `Animal`. You're assigning an individual element which is either a `Dog` or `Cat` to a reference of that particular animal, but the object is of type `Animal`, even though the actual element is a `Dog` or a `Cat`. The compiler doesn't know *what kind* of `Animal` it is, without a cast.

For that statement to work, you need a cast to the appropriate type.

```
Dog lassie = (Dog) animals[0];
Cat fluffy = (Cat) animals[1];
```

Polymorphism though, isn't really used in this manner, since the idea is that you as the user, don't need to know the specific type of `Animal`, just that it's an `Animal`.

Suppose your `Animal` class defined an abstract method called `speak()` and your subclasses both implemented it, `System.out.println("Woof")` for a `Dog` and `System.out.println("Meow")` for a `Cat`, to keep it simple.

Example:

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public abstract void speak();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   @Override
   public void speak() {
       System.out.println("Woof!");
   }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
   @Override
   public void speak() {
       System.out.println("Meow!");
   }
}
```

If you then had your array as such:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[20];
animals[0] = new Dog();
animals[1] = new Cat();

for (Animal a : animals) {
    a.speak();  // you don't know what Animal it is, but the proper speak method will be called.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how use polymorphism. The idea is that once you added elements to a polymorphic collection, you should treat them all as just Animal. If they have different behavior, then this goes into polymorphic methods that are defined on the superclass and implemented in the subclass. Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a type of `Animal` to `Dog` (assuming `Dog` inherits from `Animal`), the assignment can't work, as the compiler can only guarantee that the object is of a type of `Animal`, it could be a `Horse` for all it knows

But you can cast `Animal` to `Dog` or `Cat` again, assuming that `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from `Animal`

```
Dog lassie = (Dog)animals[0];
Cat fluffy = (Cat)animals[1];
```

Having said that, I would be very careful about blind casting values in this way.

When defining an array as `Animal`, you are basically saying, I don't care about the contents, so long as it meets the contractual requirements of the class/interface `Animal`, beyond that, you shouldn't care

Answer (score 0):

The static type is `Animal` for `animal[0]` and `animal[1]`. So basically you're telling java:

Let this `Dog lassie` be an animal. And let this `Cat fluffy` be an animal. But not all animals are necessarily cats or dogs. See why Java might get upset with this?

You need to reassure Java using a caste:

```
Dog lassie = (Dog) animals[0];
Cat fluffy = (Cat) animals[1];
```